# Two dlls (service and interface). Using interface methods to various projects?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, web-applications, dll

I have a pretty big web app  which consists of a few different projects. I have to add some extra functionality (account validations, searching products etc). I was provided with two `.dll` files let's say `Services.dll` and `Interfaces.dll`.

`Services.dll` includes three classes with several methods in them and `Interfaces.dll` their interfaces.

Example:

```
//SERVICES.DLL
using Interfaces;

namespace Services
{
  internal class User : IUser
  {
    public Users GetUserByName (string Name)
    {
      //Implementation
    }
  }
}

//INTERFACES.DLL
namespace Interfaces
{
  public interface IUser
  {
    Users GetUserByName(string Name);
  }

  public class Users
  {
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
  }
}
```

For implementing the extra features I need to use these methods in several of my included projects. How can this be achieved using the provided dlls? Is creating a web service using the dll a way? And then how both of them will be consumed by the service?

Everything is implemented in C# and Net 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

I say it depends on how often these dlls are updated. You should choose whatever method is more convenient to update. The web service could be easy to update but could add unnecessary layers to your app and may be subject to bandwidth limitations. You could consider just adding the dll files in your web app directly as a reference to the files. Then update the dlls with new versions would require a rebuild/republish.

Comment: Ok I think I will add use them as a reference. My problem is now on how will I access and use the methods of Services.dll since the class User for example is declared as internal?

Comment: @istar internal is by definition access only in the same assembly, so you can't unless the methods are accessible through `IUser`. Also `User GetUserByName(string Name);` wouldn't work because it's returning a `User` - it should return an `IUser` to be accessible.

Comment: I corrected the code above. `GetUserByName` returns a `Users` which `Users` is declared in `Interfaces.dll`.